# CSS Reset vs * wild card

Tags: html, css

Why cant I just do a simple reset of:

`* { margin: 0; padding: 0; font-size: 100% }`

instead of:

```
html, body, div, span, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
abbr, address, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, samp,
small, strong, sub, sup, var,
b, i,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    outline:0;
    font-size:100%;
    vertical-align:baseline;
    background:transparent;
}
```

Comment: Per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Common_CSS_Questions#Use_of_the_.2A_selector) "The use of the * selector should be minimized as it is a slow selector, especially when not used as the first element of a selector. Its use should be avoided as much as possible."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all you can.

Answering the question: because you probably don't want to have all elements with specified parameters. For example you do not have inputs, buttons etc. there.

Comment: I just notice the 2nd reset almost everywhere and was wondering why such   a wordy selection when one line can suffice.

Comment: @RobertRocha "*" selects all element which takes longer to proceed and you generally dont want to have a bunch of unnesserairy rules. Its good to just use the most common ones minus the ones you dont want to have the rule on.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe because type selectors have more [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity) than the universal selector.

Or because this CSS reset doesn't want to match all elements, like `input`s.

Answer (score 2):

Applying all those styles to all elements would result in unanticipated styling. Please check out the following textbox, dropdown, and textarea reset with all your reset styles:

```
<input type="text" value="foo" />
<select>
<option>Foo</option>
<option>Bar</option>
</select>
<textarea rows="10" columns="30">foo</textarea>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/esm63r30/

Pretty bare!

Comment: Well I didn't include the border.

Comment: @RobertRocha Indeed, but the point is if you apply these styles so broadly, you may end up with unintended stylings. The reset you included targets specific elements for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

Using a CSS reset is a powerful way of quickly achieving a good starting point for your design, allowing you to save time and clutter when coding. Instead of blatantly resetting everything you should find the tags you commonly want to reset and choose default values that work well according to each project individually.

**Using A Wildcard Reset**

It is possible to reset each and every HTML tag that may or may not have a style attached to it with a wildcard CSS statement. While this is quick and easy it may also have undesirable effects.

By removing all default formatting from all HTML tags you force yourself to have to create custom styles for these tags. Remember, you may only think about div, span, ul, li and other common elements, completely forgetting about abbr, pre and cite.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common technique called a CSS reset. Different browsers use different default margins, causing sites to look different by margins. The * means "all elements" (a universal selector), so we are setting all elements to have zero margins, and zero padding, thus making them look the same in all browsers.